# I did some changes on css file, bu that does not reflects in yii application view

Tags: yii

I did some changes on form.css file (Which is used for form view) but that doesn't reflect on the form view. Whenever i look through inspect element on browser it shows the old css class files. I also tried to delete the caches via cloudflare and i also try enabled the debug mode

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', True);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

but no use

Comment: Try holding `Ctrl` then pressing refresh `F5` to force a fresh reload (reset cache)

Comment: What is the url/path of the css file you changed?

Comment: I put the css file in css folder. Even i tried rename the file, but still problem is there. Also I tried deleting the all files inside the runtime folder but no use.

Answer (score 1):

YII exports files to assets folder when it accessed for the first time. So search for your css file in projectRoot/assets folder and delete the folder containing your file.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Already deleted all the assets folder content and runtime folder contents. Still no use.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the all files inside the runtime folder. I once again edited the css file to change the value. It worked.